# php/curl how to add root certificate

Tags: php, ssl, curl, certificate, ssl-certificate

For a web application which is able to mount users directories I want to provide a option for the user to upload his root certificate to use curl over ssl.

I tried to set the capath to the upload directory (CURLOPT_CAPATH => $capath) but I still get this error message:

```
[CURL] Error while making request: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK
```

If I try to set the cert additionally to the path (but I would prefer to set up curl in a way to accept all certificates signed by a bunch of root certificates provided by the user).

Anyway, if I set for test purpose:

```
CURLOPT_CAPATH => $capath
CURLOPT_CAINFO => $capath."/myrootcert.der"
```

I get this error message:

```
[CURL] Error while making request: error setting certificate verifylocations:\n  CAfile: /foo/bar/cacertroot.der\n  CApath: /foo/bar/\n (error code: 77)
```

Any hints what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Error code 77 is CURLE_SSL_CACERT_BADFILE. Are you sure that the path to the CA file is correct and the file is readable by the user running this script?

Comment: I double checked the path, it is correct. Also the file should be readable by the user running the script since the same script uploads the file and can also remove it.